# No download link for podcast #107

Tags: bug, status-completed, podcast

Previous podcasts have had a download button so that you can listen to the podcast without an internet connection:

[image: There is a download button next to the share button]

However this is not the case with the [latest podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/01/podcast-107-just-trying-non-terrible/):

[image: No download button]

(and before you ask, there also isn't any download button on SoundCloud when you navigate to the page manually)

I presume this is a setting on SoundCloud that someone forgot to tick. Could someone please flick the switch?

Comment: This was fixed yesterday: http://disq.us/p/1ibtw6j

Comment: @D.G. thanks, I noticed. I've flagged for a SE mod to add the status-completed tag.